# First Index Number Pop Up Last in Table

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, admin

I'm using SB Admin Bootstrap.

My table didn't functioning as it should be (should be user can search the data in table and data arranged well), but :

[image: 1st index number is at the bottom of the table]

[image: The result appeared but it prompt "No matching found"]

This is my php code:

```
<div class="box-content">
    <?php
        if ($result) {
    ?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">User ID</th>
                <th class="text-left">Username</th>
                <th class="text-left">Password</th>
                <th class="text-left">Full Name</th>
                <th class="text-left">Task</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo '
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="center">' . $row['userid'] . '</td>
                <td class="center">' . $row['username'] . '</td>
                <td class="center">' . $row['password'] . '</td>
                <td class="center">' . $row['fullname'] . '</td>
                <td class="center">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white zoom-in"></i>                                            
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>                                            
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> 

                </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>';
        }}
    ?>
        </table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer moved from comment*

You are repeating `<tbody>` element, so script are just taking first occurrence of this tag and executing some functions, leaving every further `<tbody>` intact.

Move  out of loop, it must be unique in table.